# Cannot grant permissions in MySQL using root (or any account) - "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'"

Tags: mysql, permissions, remote-access, freebsd, sql-grant

I have been searching all over this and other forums but I've hit a wall.  I had a working MySQL installation but I think when I tried to restore a couple schema's recently I think I more than I expected perhaps.

So here is my issue:
I could no longer access the DB from any of my apps.  They are getting access denied.  When I researched i found their accounts are gone (hence the above comment about "more than I expected".

I typically use MySQL Workbench but couldn't access the DB either from my client PC (linux Kubuntu). So I went to the host command line...

I can log in at the command line with root@localhost. Note, mysql is running in a FreeBSD jail on FreeNas.  I originally had a password but saw some different options for resetting the password might help including removing it. So that's why it's now empty.

When I try to execute the following

```
grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'localhost' identified by 'PASSWORD' with grant option;`
```

I get the following error

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

I have checked via the user table permissions granted...everything appears like I should be able to do this.

```
`+-----------+------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------+------------+
| host      | user       | password                                  | Grant_priv | Super_priv |
+-----------+------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------+------------+
| localhost | root       |                                           | Y          | Y          |
| 127.0.0.1 | root       | *E3FCFF11BABD5D85A4D6F6A30AF940F8333E2495 | Y          | Y          |
| %         | root       | *E3FCFF11BABD5D85A4D6F6A30AF940F8333E2495 | Y          | Y          |
+-----------+------------+-------------------------------------------+------------+------------+`
```

I've done `select User();` and `select current_user();` to confirm who I am.

I've restarted in --skip-grant-tables to try and 'reset permissions'.

At this point I'm lost on what else to try.  Any thoughts or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok - figured out my issue. This link was helpful.
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16397/cannot-grant-privileges-as-root

I found my user table was inline with a 5.1 version of MySQL vs. the 5.5. I was running. I had run `mysql_upgrade` before and this time I had to rerun with `mysql_upgrade --force`.  This resolved the permission issues.